# How to apply `where` query on the data received after `include` in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize as an ORM for my project. I have two models User and Role. A User can have one Role but a Role can have multiple Users.
Here is my query:

```
const users=User.findAll(where:{last_name:'raj'}, include:{Role});
```

This query gives me an array of all the users whose last name is `raj`. For example:

```
users=[
  {
    id:"1",
    last_name:'raj',
    .....
    .....
    roles:[
      {id:"role1", name:"admin"},   
      {id:"role1", name:"super-admin"},
      ............
    ]
  },
  {
    id:"5",
    last_name:'raj',
    .....
    .....
    roles:[
      {id:"role1", name:"coordinator"},   
      {id:"role1", name:"super-admin"},
      ............
    ]
  },
  .........
  .........
]
```

But I wanted all the User with the last name 'raj' and who has a role:'admin'. After I have received the users array I apply a filter method to filter out all the users with a role of `admin`.

This adding a uneccesary processing. Is it possible to specify the logic to filter user who has a role as `admin` in the sequelize query itself?

Please guide me.

Comment: As I see one user has several roles (judging by data example). So what's correct: the description or the example?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add `where` option to included model like this:

```js
const users=User.findAll({
  where:{ last_name:'raj' },
  include:[{
    model: Role,
    where: {
      name: 'admin'
    }
  }]
});
```